# textures are not appearing on viewport (only color of my texture appearing)

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Textures are not appearing on the viewport (only color of my texture appearing).

[image]

My UV

[image]

---

Edit:

UV is looking like this my texture image is extremely small to my top.
How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: How does your UVs look like? Try to unwrap your model if you haven't already: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM Also I'd suggest take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.

Comment: my answer is below

Answer (score 1):

I think you answer your self already ... Texture doesn't appear because it is too small ... Technically texture is there, but repeated in such small size that appears as single color.

Select all vertices of your UV map and Scale (S) it down.

Comment: Upvoted just for the sake ;)